# How to ensure that consistent hashing works?

Tags: cassandra, scalability, consistent-hashing

I'm going to implement consistent hashing over a bunch of nodes. Each node has a limited capacity (let's say 1GB). I starts with one node and when it's getting full I'm gonna add another node and use consistent hashing to redistribute the data and move forward by adding new nodes. However there are still chances that a node gets full. I know some nosql databases such as cassandra uses consistent hashing to do something similar to what i'm doing. How can I avoid nodes from overflowing using consistent hashing?

Answer (score 4):

Cassandra does not use consistent hashing in a way you described.

Each table has a partition key (you can think about it as a primary key or first part of it in RDBMS terminology), this key is hashed using murmur3 algorithm. The whole hash space forms a continuos ring from lowest possible hash to the highest. After that this ring is divided into chunks (vnodes, 256 by default) and these chunks are fairly distributed among multiple nodes. Each node hosts not only it's own part of the ring, but also maintains replicated copy of other vnodes according to replication factor.

This way of doing things helps to solve a lot of problems:

- balance data load among all cluster nodes, no specific node can be overloaded (data size, reads and writes are evenly distributed, no hot points)
- if you add a new node to a cluster, it will handle it's own part of ring and pull required vnodes automatically from other nodes. No need to manual resharding.
- if node fails, due to replication you won't miss any data because it is already stored on other nodes. In this case you can decomission failed nodes so all other nodes will redistribute failed ring part among them. No need to have complex switching scenarios for failed db nodes.

Of course, you can always implement similar DB behaviour on top of any RDBMS in your application layer, but it is always much harder and not error-prone than using already existing battle-tested solution.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that consistent hashing guarantees evenness of *new* incoming records not existing ones, right? Unless you take the time to redistribute records everytime a new partition is added, I don't see how it's possible to guarantee evenness across all partitions

Answer (score 1):

I guess you know how keys gets moved from one node to another node, when a node is added or deleted. Coming to your question of how uniform distribution happens?

You can have your own logic here to make it happen. You keep on monitoring all the nodes in the hash if any node is getting hot(Handling more keys) insert another node before this node so that the load will be distributed among the old and the new nodes. Similar way if any of the the nodes are under utilised you can delete them so that load will be shift to the next node.

Hope this help..!!